# Is there a way to live switch languages in angular 8?

Tags: angular, angular-i18n

I was watching some tutorials to make the frontend of my app with option to switch between english and spanish

Reading some tutorials about translating my content I found the i18n. But aparently I have to run "ng serve --configuration=es" to put the app in spanish and run "ng serve --configuration=en" to put it on enlgish...and of course that's not Ideal

I investigated a little an found in their github page for i18n that there is no support for live switch but they are working on it...that was on 2018, so I want to be sure is already possible to switch dynamically between languages before trying to dive in into that, or if I have to try another frontend framework.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***YES......!!!!!!!!!!!!***

**Using Ngx-Translate you can do that**

Here is the library which is widely used for angular internationalization which changes the languages live on the user-selected.

> https://github.com/ngx-translate/core

Git hub Repo show's full documentation and along with that, you may find many videos about NGX-Translate.

Few links to the tutorial.

- http://www.ngx-translate.com/
- https://alligator.io/angular/ngx-translate/
- https://www.codeandweb.com/babeledit/tutorials/how-to-translate-your-angular8-app-with-ngx-translate

I hope, I answer your question.